# Is it possible for someone to build a linux embedded board at home?

Tags: pcb, embedded, lcd, linux

I am wondering if it is possible to build an embedded linux board at home that has basic features like USB , serial and linux support but is powerfull enough to drive an LCD. I have looked at this tutorial http://hforsten.com/making-embedded-linux-computer.html and it is very handly but it cannot drive an LCD.

Comment: It's become easier than ever these days to put together basic ARM-based linux PCs as some manufacturers now make nearly complete System in Package units (like [TI](https://octavosystems.com/octavo_products/osd335x/)), just add a board, connectors, some flash memory (like an SD card) and some power supplies and bingo.

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by `drive an LCD` ... you can connect an LCD to an arduino, which is wayyyyy less powerful

Comment: @jsotola based on my accepted answer and comments, OP means an external consumer monitor.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at something like a Raspberry Pi, Orange Pi or ASUS Tinker. All these are readily assembled and drive conventional LCD monitors. Making your own board is simply in-efficient unless you are building commercial quantities.

Comment: By drive an LCD I mean have an LCD that can display Xorg apps ran by linux. The best LCD for my project would be a raw lcd but VGA/HDMI can work too

Comment: You cannot make your own board by hand. Many traces are LVDS and need a professional router to calculate flight time, etc. These boards have data and address lines running at GHZ frequencies with pico-second rise/fall times. Don't build what you can buy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Doing the same exact process except choosing a controller that includes direct video.

Keep in mind, any random controller may not drive an lcd directly, but if you have Linux and USB, you can use a USB LCD or a usb to video adapter.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a controller that includes video?

Comment: There are millions of embedded systems on chips you can use. I don't have a specific in mind and this website does not do specific recommendations like that. Keep in mind, any controller like that may not drive an lcd directly, but if you have Linux and USB, you can use a USB LCD or a usb to video adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the USB to video adapter. I will be definitely trying it out :D

Comment: See for example: https://hackaday.com/2011/01/02/classic-game-emulation-on-the-dockstar/ They took a video less embedded computer and added USB video.